# Create Taxonomy list dependent based upon the other taxonomy list drupal 8?

Tags: php, drupal

I have two different taxonomies for example car's and model's.

I have to add the above two taxonomies as select fields in a third taxonomy.

The functionality of two fields should be something like this:

```
If i select BMW in cars
  then All models of BMW should display in model's list
```

How could I achieve that?

Comment: Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific/clear (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

this will be easy my friend

first you have to install simple hierarchical select module from here :https://www.drupal.org/project/shs

then go to taxonomy and make new taxonomy and lets us make it's name CarsInformation

then add terms in it for your car names like BMW , TOYOTA , HONDA , FORD ...

and also add terms by models that you want and make it a child for the car name and it will be like this

[explaining](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffM16.png)

and now go to your content type and open Mange form display and from widget choose simple hierarchical select and now it will work